# How to change the default shell in NixOS?

Tags: shell, fish, nixos

At the moment I need to set the fish shell to be my default shell on NixOS and there is no official documentation on how to do that *declaratively* (not by running `chsh`) in NixOS.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In your `configuration.nix`,

```
{ pkgs, ... }:

{
  ...

  programs.fish.enable = true;

  users.users.<myusername> = {   
    ...  
    shell = pkgs.fish;
    ...
  };
}
```

Followed by `nixos-rebuild switch`.

More info in [NixOS Wiki](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Command_Shell#Changing_default_shell).

Comment: How do you make fish default for all users?

Comment: `users.defaultUserShell = pkgs.fish;`  [Docs](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Command_Shell#Changing_default_shell)

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the `home-server` user configuration using flakes?